# How to fetch the token from data store then initiate to intercept function of Interceptor Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, coroutine

I'm using `data store` ( because it's better than shared preferences ) to store the token. In `intercept` function override by Interceptor I want to get the token from `data store` but not to use `runBlocking`. I used `runBlocking` and it worked but my PM doesn't want to use `runBlocking` . You guys have any ideas to replace `runBlocking` ?

I was asked Chat GPT but the solution be answered is :

```
fun fetchTokenFromDataStore(): Deferred<String> = coroutineScope {
    async {
        // Fetch the token from data store asynchronously
        // Replace this with your actual logic to fetch the token
        delay(1000) // Simulating an async operation
        return@async "your_token_here"
    }
}

fun makeHttpRequestWithToken(token: String) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("your_request_url_here")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            // Handle failure
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            // Handle response
        }
    })
}

// Usage
fun performHttpRequest() {
    // Fetch the token asynchronously
    val tokenDeferred = fetchTokenFromDataStore()

    // Once the token is fetched, initiate the HTTP request
    tokenDeferred.invokeOnCompletion { throwable ->
        if (throwable == null) {
            val token = tokenDeferred.getCompleted()
            makeHttpRequestWithToken(token)
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

I know it wrong but I have no idea to do that. You guys please help me!